# XML Serialization of deeply nested subclassed objects

Tags: c#, inheritance, xml-serialization

I have a code base that works frequently in Insurance Industry ACORD XML. The ACORD specification is very large, and it encourages both users and vendors to define their own customer nodes to be added into the specification.  So for the given XML file below, in it base state

```
<ACORD>
    <SignonRq>
        <SignonTransport></SignonTransport>
        <ClientApp>
            <Org></Org>
            <Name></Name>
            <Version></Version>
        </ClientApp>
    </SignonRq>
</ACORD>
```

I am able to serialize and deserialize it into C# objects using the following code:

```
ACORD acord;
using (var reader = new StringReader(xml))
{
    acord = (ACORD)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
return acord;

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "ACORD")]
public class ACORD
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "SignonRq")]
    public SignonRq SignonRq { get; set; }
    
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "InsuranceSvcRq")]
    public InsuranceSvcRq InsuranceSvcRq { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "SignonRq")]
public class SignonRq
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "SignonTransport")]
    public SignonTransport SignonTransport { get; set; }
    
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "ClientApp")]
    public ClientApp ClientApp { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "ClientApp")]
public class ClientApp
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Org")]
    public string Org { get; set; }
    
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Version")]
    public string Version { get; set; }
}
```

But once the vendor or the client decide they need their own company specific node on ClientApp called <com.mycompany_IsInteral></com.mycopany_IsInteral> the pattern falls apart. I can easily subclass *ClientApp* to *MyCompanyClientApp* with an IsInternal property, but the serializer would ignore the new node and create a base ClientApp when deserializing from XML, and just assume the subclass was the base class when serializing. I could also subclass the serializer itself, but it doesnt look like the overrides provide the degree of granularity we would need unless I am missing something.

I rack my brain periodically trying to determine how I can keep this pattern (and keep the base classes in their own seperate reusable DLL) but still allow for polymorphism.  I have frequently given up and updated the base classes in different projects, and in another project I simply did away with the serializer and manually parse the XML into its final form. But these solutions don't promote code re-use.

I thought I would see what the big brains thought about this issue?

TIA
_Peter

Comment: A couple of years ago I faced the problem of generating new XML structures for existing classes. I solved it  with Visitor pattern, added a new method GenerateSpecialXML into existing classes with parameter (Visitor v) to it. Is expanding your classes acceptable?

Comment: In principle, you may use Object extension pattern and transmit your classes to it via Factory (If you want you classes to remain untouchable.)

Comment: THanks but I dont think a visitor will help with this since the underlying structure of the objects can't change with a visitor pattern. And an object extension would require serializing to the base classes still, then manually replacing some of the object or manually updating the properties. We lose all real benefit from the XML Serialization.